# How can I remove the blue square that overlays UITabBarItem when selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have an iPad app (Xcode 5, iOS 7, ARC and Storyboards). I have a `UITabBarController`, and each scene has a `UITabBarItem`.

When I tap a tab bar item, it goes to the correct scene, but the "current" tab bar item image is overlaid by a "blue box".

How can I replace that "blue box" with a different image? (I don't want to change the color; I want to replace it with a different image).

Comment: How did you create the tab bar items? Did you add images and/or text?

Comment: Used XCode 5 Storyboard; drag and drop (it was the easiest way)... added images and text in Storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images you use for a tab bar item have to have their `renderingMode` be, `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` or they will appear as blue squares (templates). The document called "Tab Bars", says this,

> Tab Bar Item Icons
>
> Each item in a tab bar can have a custom selected image and unselected
>   image. You can specify these images when you initialize a tab bar item
>   using the initWithTitle:image:selectedImage: method. Note that a tab
>   bar item image will be automatically rendered as a template image
>   within a tab bar, unless you explicitly set its rendering mode to
>   UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. For more information, see Template
>   Images.

I don't think you can set them up in the storyboard, so you should do it in the controller's init method,

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.jpg"];
        img  = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        [self.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:img];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @spokane-dude, If the unselected image is working for you, you really only need to do the setSelectedImage: part of the code I provided (I updated to take the other part out). Did you try that? I'm still not sure how you got the unselected image to work from IB -- if I set the image there, I just get a gray square the same size as my image.

Comment: It is possible to do it in storyboard only, you just need to have them on transparent background, then they will not become blue squares.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Xcode error that will be fixed in 8.2 release. This is the Apple official note about this problem.Look in the link for Interface Builder > Resolved Issues > UITabBarController https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3+ version of [rdelmar's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225998/3151675):

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let img = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pic").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        tabBarItem.selectedImage = img
    }
}
```